# Python, generate pair of distinct random numbers

Tags: python, numpy, random

I want to use

```
np.random.randint(4, size=2)
```

to generate a pair of distinct random numbers from 0 to 3. The problem is that it sometimes gives (0,0), (3,3) etc. Is there a way to force the numbers to be distinct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you could use [`random.choice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html):

```
import numpy as np

np.random.choice(a=np.arange(4), size=2, replace=False)
```

or, more concise (as [Nuageux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6350421/nuageux) pointed out):

```
np.random.choice(a=4, size=2, replace=False)
```

Comment: First time I ran it, I got  array([1, 1])

Comment: You need to set `replace=False` to avoid duplication.

Comment: where do I have to include that?

Comment: @kazemakase: thanks! updated (sorry. ninja-editing...)

Comment: According to the documentation, can't you use just `4` instead of `np.arrange(4)`?

Answer (score 2):

for people who don't wanna use `numpy`

```
import random


left_end = 0
right_end = 3
length = 2
random.sample(range(left_end, right_end), k=length)
```

also you can wrap it in `tuple` if you need, since [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample) returns `list` object